# Understanding multiple conditions in a C loop

Tags: c, lua

There is a piece of C code

```
int i, j = 0;
for (i = 0, j = n-1; i < n; j = i++) {
    // array operations
}
```

that I'm trying to convert into Lua code

```
local j = n-1
for i = 1, n do -- arrays are 1-based in Lua
    -- array operations
    j = i+1
end
```

but for some reason Lua code doesn't work. Am I getting that C loop right?

Comment: What is code snippet in C intended to do? Is it working as you expected and what is `n` initialized ?

Comment: The code should detect if the point is inside a polygon, n is number of vertices. Complete function by Randolph Franklin is here: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/insidepoly/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine an array as a circular buffer. `i` is the current item and `j` is always the previous one:

```
n = 5
local j = n
for i = 1, n do -- arrays are 1-based in Lua
    -- array operations
    io.write('i=', i, ' j=', j, '\n')
    j = i
end
```

#### [Demo](http://ideone.com/Sif8Q):

```
i=1 j=5
i=2 j=1
i=3 j=2
i=4 j=3
i=5 j=4
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not know Lua but what the C code does is:

At every iteration:

Assign i to j: j = i;
Then increment i by 1: i = i+1;

Looks like your Lua code should be j = i instead of j = i+1

Answer (score 1):

No, `j` is always one less than `i` unless `i` equals `0`, then `j` is `n-1`. So `j = i+1` should probably be `j = i` as `i` will be increased in the next iteration.

I don't know Lua so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not best to transform it into a lua for loop; use a while loop:

```
local i , j = 0 , n-1
while i < n do
    --array operations
    j = i
    i = i + 1
end
```

Not that the code makes alot of sense.... if you want to convert to 1 based indexing as well use `i , j = 1 , n` and `i<=n`