# converting for loop from c to python

Tags: python, c, for-loop

I'm converting some c code to python. Can someone convert this for loop from the c programming language to python equivalent with variable names and all?

```
 int i, j, c = 0;
 int n = SOME CONSTANT, not less than 2, like 3 4 5 6..
 for (i = 0, j = n-1; i < n; j = i++){

 }
```

I think with a for-loop this isn't possible. Maybe like this:

```
j = n - 1
i = 0
while True:
  do stuff

  if i < n:
     break
  i = i + 1
  j = i
```

Very ugly if anyone has a better solution please share

Comment: Where did `n` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Imagine an array as a circular buffer. i is the current item and j is always the previous one:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8026752/4279)

```
j = n - 1
for i in xrange(n):
    # do stuff
    # ...
    j = i
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this, and depending on the usage, you get slightly different behaviours in terms of time. Anyway, if you don't have any special need, you can use the range function, that since Python 3.x has become a "lazy" function. So it won't take too much memory.

Do like this:

```
J = n - 1
for i in range(0, n):
    #The body of your code goes here#
    j = i
```

And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, j in zip(range(n), [n - 1] + range(n - 1)):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: if you use `zip()` then you could use `range(-1, n-1)`. It exploits `a[-1] == a[n-1]` where `n == len(a)`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, yes this is true, but only if he's using i and j as index of an iterator. Technically it's not equivalent to the `for` loop he gave in C (because `j` will be -1 instead of n - 1), so that might not be desirable depending on how he uses `j`.